# Edge saying Function expected on Babel'ed code

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, microsoft-edge

I have some pretty straightforward code that runs through Webpack -> Babel:

```js
let isOn = false;
const videoTag = doc.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
const trackTag = doc.createElement('track');
const id = someGlobalIHave;

function setMode() {
  const tracks = [...videoTag.textTracks].filter(t => t.kind === 'captions');
  tracks.forEach(track => {
    track.mode = isOn ? 'showing' : 'hidden';
  });
}

trackTag.setAttribute('default', '');
trackTag.setAttribute('src', `/mysource/${id}/captions`);
trackTag.setAttribute('kind', `captions`);

videoTag.appendChild(trackTag);

setMode();
```

My global error handler is sending me the error `Function expected` for Edge 17 only, with the lovely minified location of  Line 6, Column 8029.

That pretty much amounts to this:

```js
function s(){
  [...r.textTracks].filter(e=>"captions"===e.kind)
  .forEach(e=>{e.mode=n?"showing":"hidden"})}
```

My cursor says I'm at 8029 right between the opening curl and the opening square bracket.

What idiosyncratic Edge thing am I missing here?

***Update***

Here is some code I just ran in console, after Simo's answer

```js
// doc is defined above from document being passed into method

const videoTag = doc.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
const x = [1];
[...videoTag.textTracks] // just running this line throws Function expected
Array.from(videoTag.textTracks) // works as expected
[...x,2] // returns [1,2]
videoTag.textTracks.filter(t => true); // Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Edge has issues with iterator protocol, so maybe you can try to replace spread operator with something like `Array.from`.
Basically you are unable to iterate or use spread operator on NodeList.

Comment: Ah yeah Array.from works but see my edit before I select answer

Answer (score 0):

Last time i checked, IE edge didn't support the spread operator.
You don't need to use the spread operator in your case. Array filter already creates a new array.

```
 const tracks = videoTag.textTracks.filter(t => t.kind === 'captions');
    tracks.forEach(track => {
     track.mode = isOn ? 'showing' : 'hidden';
  });
```

Comment: Didn't know that about filter. Secondarily, going to edit question above before selecting an answer.